# Ultrafilters and convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, filters

I'm reading a paper on LINEAR SOFIC GROUPS AND ALGEBRAS by ARZHANTSEVA, and I can't understand this part of the paper on page 3:

Let $\omega$ be a non-principal (or free) ultrafilter and $(n_k)_k$ a sequence of natural numbers such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} n_k= \infty $. The cartesian product $\Pi M_{n_k}(F)$ is an algebra. Let us define:
$$\rho_{\omega}: \Pi M_{n_k}(F) \to [0,1],~ \rho_{\omega} ( (a_k)_k ) := \lim_{k \to \omega} \rho(a_k) $$

I completely understand the first and second line, but I don't know how can $k$ converge to $\omega$, since $k$ is a natural number whereas $\omega$ is an ultrafilter.

Comment: Perhaps they meant $|\omega|$- the cardinality of $\omega$?

Comment: Limits with respect to ultrafilters (or just filters) are defined by: $x=\lim_{k\to\omega}y_k$ iff, for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $\{k:y_k\in U\}\in\omega$.

Comment: In other sources you may see that limit written $\omega$-$\lim\rho(a_k)$. That the limit (as defined above by Andreas Blass) exists follows from the compactness of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have an ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k$, where $(a_k)_k$ is any sequence (in a compact Hausdorff space ,like $[0,1]$ here), is the limit along the ultrafilter $\omega$, more commonly denoted as $\omega$-$\lim_k a_k$ and which is the unique $a \in [0,1]$ so that for each neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ we have that the set $\{k\mid a_k \in U\}$ is in the ultrafilter $U$. By general considerations, such an $a$ always exists in a compact Hausdorff space (and it's one of the cluster points of the set $\{a_k\mid k\in \Bbb N\}$ as well).